# Python and global declaration

Tags: python, global

I'm having trouble trying to resolve this error:

`SyntaxWarning: name 'meaning5' is assigned to before global declaration`

Basically my program needs to allow the user to input their name, the program then calculates the users lucky number based on the assignment of a=1, b=2 etc.

This is my code so far:

```
from time import sleep

tempNumb = 0
tempLNN1a = 0
tempLNN1b = 0
tempLNN2a = 0
tempLNN2b = 0
varLNN1 = 0
varLNN2 = 0
LNN = 0
tempLNNa = 0
tempLNNb = 0
templetter = "nothing"
meaning1 = "Natural leader"
meaning2 = "Natural peacemaker"
meaning3 = "Creative and optimistic"
meaning4 = "Hard worker"
meaning5 = "Value freedom"
meaning6 = "Carer and a provider"
meaning7 = "Thinker"
meaning8 = "Have diplomatic skills"
meaning9 = "Selfless and generous"
global templetter
global tempNumb
global tempLNN1a
global tempLNN1b
global tempLNN2a
global tempLNN2b
global varLNN1
global varLNN1
global LNN
global tempLNNa
global tempLNNb
global meaning1
global meaning2
global meaning3
global meaning4
global meaning5
global meaning6
global meaning7
global meaning8
global meaning9


def mainprogram():
    sleep(1)
    print("-----------------------")
    print("Welcome to LUCKY NAME \n         NUMBERS")
    print("-----------------------")
    sleep(1)
    firstname = input("Please input your first \nname in all capitals\n")
    if firstname == firstname.upper():
        print("-----------------------")
        sleep(1)
        surname = input("Please input your surname \nin  all capitals\n")
        if surname == surname.upper():
            print("-----------------------")
            print("Calculating your Lucky \nName Number...")
            for i in range(len(firstname)):
                templetter = firstname[i]
                calculate()
                tempfirstname()
            for i in range(len(surname)):
                templetter = surname[i]
                calculate()
                tempsurname()
            finalcalculate()


def calculate():
    if templetter == "A":
        tempNumb = 1
    elif templetter == "B":
        tempNumb = 2
    elif templetter == "C":
        tempNumb = 3
    elif templetter == "D":
        tempNumb = 4
    elif templetter == "E":
        tempNumb = 5
    elif templetter == "F":
        tempNumb = 6
    elif templetter == "G":
        tempNumb = 7
    elif templetter == "H":
        tempNumb = 8
    elif templetter == "I":
        tempNumb = 9
    elif templetter == "J":
        tempNumb = 1
    elif templetter == "K":
        tempNumb = 2
    elif templetter == "L":
        tempNumb = 3
    elif templetter == "M":
        tempNumb = 4
    elif templetter == "N":
        tempNumb = 5
    elif templetter == "O":
        tempNumb = 6
    elif templetter == "P":
        tempNumb = 7
    elif templetter == "Q":
        tempNumb = 8
    elif templetter == "R":
        tempNumb = 9
    elif templetter == "S":
        tempNumb = 1
    elif templetter == "T":
        tempNumb = 2
    elif templetter == "U":
        tempNumb = 3
    elif templetter == "V":
        tempNumb = 4
    elif templetter == "W":
        tempNumb = 5
    elif templetter == "X":
        tempNumb = 6
    elif templetter == "Y":
        tempNumb = 7
    elif templetter == "Z":
        tempNumb = 8
    else:
        "You managed to break it."
        mainprogram()

def tempfirstname():
    varLNN1 = varLNN1 + tempNumb

def tempsurname():
    varLNN2 = varLNN2 + tempNumb

def finalcalculate():
    varLNN1 = str(varLNN1)
    varLNN2 = str(varLNN2)
    tempLNN1a = varLNN1[0]
    tempLNN1b = varLNN1[1]
    tempLNN2a = varLNN2[0]
    tempLNN2b = varLNN2[1]
    varLNN1 = int(tempLNN1a) + int(tempLNN1b)
    varLNN2 = int(tempLNN2a) + int(tempLNN2b)
    LNN = varLNN1 + varLNN2
    LNN = str(LNN)
    tempLNNa = LNN[0]
    tempLNNb = LNN[1]
    LNN = int(tempLNNa) + int(tempLNNb)
    if LNN == 1 or "1":
        print("Your Lucky Name Number is - " + str(LNN) + " and it means you are a " + meaning1)
        loop()
    elif LNN == 2 or "2":
        print("Your Lucky Name Number is - " + str(LNN) + " and it means you are a " + meaning2)
        loop()
    elif LNN == 3 or "3":
        print("Your Lucky Name Number is - " + str(LNN) + " and it means you are " + meaning3)
        loop()
    elif LNN == 4 or "4":
        print("Your Lucky Name Number is - " + str(LNN) + " and it means you are a " + meaning4)
        loop()
    elif LNN == 5 or "5":
        print("Your Lucky Name Number is - " + str(LNN) + " and it means you " + meaning5)
        loop()
    elif LNN == 6 or "6":
        print("Your Lucky Name Number is - " + str(LNN) + " and it means you are a " + meaning6)
        loop()
    elif LNN == 7 or "7":
        print("Your Lucky Name Number is - " + str(LNN) + " and it means you are a " + meaning7)
        loop()
    elif LNN == 8 or "8":
        print("Your Lucky Name Number is - " + str(LNN) + " and it means you " + meaning8)
        loop()
    elif LNN == 9 or "9":
        print("Your Lucky Name Number is - " + str(LNN) + " and it means you are " + meaning9)
        loop()
    else:
        print("Somehow your lucky name number is too high...")
        mainprogram()
```

Comment: It should be `if LNN == 1 or LNN == "1":` and so on because `if "1"` or `if "6"` or even `if "string"` always return `True`.

Comment: Please read about lists, as they will make your code a lot better and more efficient. Try: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Answer (score 2):

Python is different than C, you don't have to declare a variable global, if you are using a global variable in a function, there you need to use global keyword.
For example:

```
     meaning5 = "Value freedom"
     def somefunction():
        global meaning5
        print meaning5
```

and as linsug has said use lists.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define all the global variable in a single function like :

```
def global_variables():
     global var_1
     global var_2
     global var_3
     global var_4
     .
     global var_n
```

And before calling anything else in main, call this function first:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    global_variables()
    # Rest of your code.
```

Might it help!.  Thanx